# My figures won't center in my div

Tags: html, image, center

For a school project, I need to make a website that's part of our project (making a Lego robot that shuffles and deals cards). In the merchandise section of my website, my figures align in a row, but they somehow aren't centered (seen here at the merchandise tab: http://i385436.hera.fhict.nl/theshufflr/index.html) and I have tried everything.

### These should be centered:

[image]

Can someone help me fix this issue? Here are the parts of code that cooperate with the merchandise tab:

```css
.et-slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.introback {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.introback img {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.introoverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 30%;
  height: 100% width: 60%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.merchoverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 30%;
  height: 100% width: 60%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.et-slide-merch {
  display: flex;
  height: 40vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  left: 30%;
  width: 100%;
}

.et-slide-merch figure {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.et-slide-merch figure img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.et-slide-merch figure figcaption {
  border: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.et-slide-merch figure figcaption h {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  color: white;
}

.et-slide-merch figure figcaption p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- Merch page -->
<section class="et-slide" id="tab-shop">
  <div class="introback">
    <img src="merch/background.jpg">
    <div class="merchoverlay">
      <h1>MERCHANDISE</h1>
      <h2>Get everything you need right here.</h2><br><br><br>
      <section class="et-slide-merch">
        <figure>
          <img src="merch/unisexhoodie.png">
          <figcaption><br>
            <h>Everyday I'm<br>Shufflin' hoodie</h>
            <br>
            <p>Unisex - XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="merch/unisexhoodie.png">
          <figcaption><br>
            <h>Everyday I'm<br>Shufflin' hoodie</h>
            <br>
            <p>Unisex - XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="merch/unisexhoodie.png">
          <figcaption><br>
            <h>Everyday I'm<br>Shufflin' hoodie</h>
            <br>
            <p>Unisex - XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="merch/unisexhoodie.png">
          <figcaption><br>
            <h>Everyday I'm<br>Shufflin' hoodie</h>
            <br>
            <p>Unisex - XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I've added a screen shot of what I'm pretty sure your getting at. Let me know (edit it) if I was wrong

Comment: That's because you are positioning using left:30% simple use text-align center to center....

Comment: `<br>` is now deprecated and should not be used, use margin or padding to space elements not `<br>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS elements with following code.

> remove   /* left: 30%; */ from "merchoverlay " and  create flex
>   environment with justify center will solve the issue.

```
 .introback {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.merchoverlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10vh;
    /* left: 30%; */
    height: 100% width: 60%;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

if you add following changes, then text (h1 anf h2) content also come to center.

```
.et-hero-tabs h2, .et-slide h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.6rem;
    color: white;
    /* width: 60%; */
}

.et-hero-tabs h1, .et-slide h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    /* width: 60%; */
}
```

Hope this will help to you.
Cheers.

Comment: it was a pleasure :) (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You got a syntax error in css code. Take the updated styles here:

```
.introoverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS:

```
.merchoverlay {
    left: unset;
    width: 100%;
}

.et-slide-merch {
    width: fit-content;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.merchoverlay h1, .merchoverlay h2 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add `flex-wrap: wrap;` and `justify-content: center;` to `.et-slide-merch` and some minor css tweaks below

```
.merchoverlay {
    /* remove left: 30%; */
    width: 100%;
}

.et-slide-merch {
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    /* remove align-items: center; */
    justify-content: center;
    /* remove height: 40vh; */
}
```

**Example:**

```css
.et-slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.introback {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.introback img {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.introoverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 30%;
  height: 100% width: 60%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.merchoverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
   /* left: 30%; remove*/
  height: 100% width: 60%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


.et-slide-merch {
  display: flex;
  /* height: 40vh; remove*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  left: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
     
   
   
    
    
}

.et-slide-merch figure {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.et-slide-merch figure img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.et-slide-merch figure figcaption {
  border: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.et-slide-merch figure figcaption h {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  color: white;
}

.et-slide-merch figure figcaption p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  color: white;
}



.merchoverlay {
    /* left: 30%; */
    width: 100%;
}

.et-slide-merch {
    flex-wrap: wrap; */
    justify-content: baseline;
    /* align-items: center; */
    justify-content: center;
    /* height: 40vh; */
}
```

```html
<!-- Merch page -->
<section class="et-slide" id="tab-shop">
  <div class="introback">
    <img src="http://i385436.hera.fhict.nl/theshufflr/merch/background.jpg">
    <div class="merchoverlay">
      <h1>MERCHANDISE</h1>
      <h2>Get everything you need right here.</h2><br><br><br>
      <section class="et-slide-merch">
        <figure>
          <img src="http://i385436.hera.fhict.nl/theshufflr/merch/unisexhoodie.png">
          <figcaption><br>
            <h>Everyday I'm<br>Shufflin' hoodie</h>
            <br>
            <p>Unisex - XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://i385436.hera.fhict.nl/theshufflr/merch/unisexhoodie.png">
          <figcaption><br>
            <h>Everyday I'm<br>Shufflin' hoodie</h>
            <br>
            <p>Unisex - XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://i385436.hera.fhict.nl/theshufflr/merch/unisexhoodie.png">
          <figcaption><br>
            <h>Everyday I'm<br>Shufflin' hoodie</h>
            <br>
            <p>Unisex - XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://i385436.hera.fhict.nl/theshufflr/merch/unisexhoodie.png">
          <figcaption><br>
            <h>Everyday I'm<br>Shufflin' hoodie</h>
            <br>
            <p>Unisex - XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```